# order of product of two elements in a group with $|a|=4$, $|b|=2$ and $a^3 b=ba$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $a$ and $b$ are two elements in a group $G$ such that $|a|=4$, $|b|=2$ and $a^3 b=ba$, then what is the order of $ab$?

What is the method to find the order of the product of two elements in a group?

Answer (score 3):

One has $(ab)^2 = (ab)(ab) = a(ba)b = a(a^3b)b=a^4b^2=e$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a^2b=a^{-1}ba.$$
Thus,
$$a^2ba^2b=e$$ or
$$a^2(ba)ab=e$$ or
$$a^2(a^3b)ab=e$$ or
$$abab=e$$ or
$$(ab)^2=e.$$
Now, if $ab=e$ then $b=a^{-1}$, which gives $a^2=e$, which is contradiction.

Thus $|ab|=2$.